# How can I return to an application in the background?

Tags: bash

I know that I can run an application in the background by putting an ampersand (`&`) at the end of the command. For instance:

```
$ rtorrent &
[1] 4618
```

starts `rtorrent` in the background.

I'd like to return to the backgrounded `rtorrent` to check whether my downloads are completed. How can I do that?

Comment: `jobs` and `fg` or `fg %n` fg for 'foreground'

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Run `fg` to put the job back onto the foreground, i.e. give it back control of the terminal. If there are multiple background jobs, run `jobs` to see a list and `fg %1`, `fg %2`, etc., to select which job to put back to the foreground.
See [the Wikipedia article on job control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_control_%28Unix%29) for more information.

If a program is running on the foreground, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to suspend it. When you do this, you'll get a shell prompt. Run `bg` to make the program keep running, but in the background.

If a background job terminates, the shell will print a notification the next time it displays a prompt. If a background job requires input from the terminal, it will automatically be suspended (“stopped”); `fg` (or `fg %42` if necessary) resumes it.

If you want to trigger a more visible notification when the program finishes, you can run something like

```
fg; play bell.ogg & xmessage "torrents downloaded"
```

The `fg` command returns when the program that it resumes finishes, so whatever you told the shell to run after `fg` will run when the program finishes. Note that if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to put the job back into the background, then the shell stops waiting and runs the following commands immediately.

Answer (score 4):

You can just run the `fg` command in the terminal.